# PHP Active Directory Fail

Tags: php, windows, ldap

```
<?php

$domain = 'xxxx.com';
$username = 'xxxxxx';
$password = 'xxxxxx';
$ldapconfig['host'] = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
$ldapconfig['port'] = 389;
$ldapconfig['basedn'] = 'dc=xxxx,dc=com';

$ds=ldap_connect($ldapconfig['host'], $ldapconfig['port']);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$dn="ou=Technology,".$ldapconfig['basedn'];
$bind=ldap_bind($ds, $username .'@' .$domain, $password);
$isITuser = ldap_search($bind,$dn,'(&(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName=' . $username. '))');
if ($isITuser) {
    echo("Login correct");
} else {
    echo("Login incorrect");
}

?>
```

I am trying to connect to Active Directory servers. But, I get an error. "Login incorrect". Actually my purpose is to add user.

Comment: Can you tell us the output of [ldap_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-error.php)

Comment: What's output of `$isITuser` and `$bind` ?

Comment: `ldap_bind` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` and you are setting the link identifier in `ldap_search` as basicly `true` or `false` which is likely why the whole thing is breaking. Maybe trade out `$bind` for `$ds` and check with the php docs on what you actually need...